# Exception support in Go programming language

Tags: go, exception

Some sources says that Go does not support exceptions for performance reasons, but some others says that Google Team implemented a few. What is the current exception support in Go?

Comment: Go does not have exceptions, it's not for performance reasons, and no one has "implemented a few". What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Everything supported by the Go language is in the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec

Comment: I'm referring to the current exception support in Go. If it has exceptions or not.

Comment: If Go did implement exceptions it would make its code so much nicer looking. Exceptions are an excellent way to separate program logic from error handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go does not have exceptions, and [that is a design decision](https://golang.org/doc/faq#exceptions), not based on performance:

> We believe that coupling exceptions to a control structure, as in the try-catch-finally idiom, results in convoluted code. It also tends to encourage programmers to label too many ordinary errors, such as failing to open a file, as exceptional.
>
> Go takes a different approach. For plain error handling, Go's multi-value returns make it easy to report an error without overloading the return value. A canonical error type, coupled with Go's other features, makes error handling pleasant but quite different from that in other languages.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thanks.

Comment: A sort-of obligatory reference to an essay which provides factual evidence for why a language's designers may chose not to have exceptions is [this](http://250bpm.com/blog:4) ;-)